# Would it be possible for a planet to have a northern or southern sunrise/sunset

Tags: planets, solar-system, electromagnetism

I was curious, if it would be possible for planet in any star system to have sunrise in the northern or southern pole due to the orientation of the planetary magnetic field?

Comment: Not all year long, but Uranus has the poles pointed at the  sun for part of the year.

Comment: Thanks John, so I guess it is plausible for a planet in a different star system to have a permanent northern or southern sunrise.

Comment: The magnetic field has absolutely nothing to do with where the sun rises and sets.

Comment: @Passing_Bye no that is not possible, the point of sunrise from the perspective of any point on the planet will move across the entire horizon. the only permanent options are the direction of spin or the opposite direction of spin, and that only works if the axis is perpendicular to the orbit.

Comment: Hello @Passing_Bye, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. I'm going to suggest two things. (a) I suggest you remove your reference to magnetic fields. It really has nothing to do with the question. (b) I suggest you ask the following: "Is it possible for a planet's axis of rotation to be tangential to the planet's orbit around the sun?" And just to keep people from posting half-informed answers to this question (because I think there will be a lot of them), I suggest you remove the [tag:magnetism] tag and add the [tag:hard-science] tag.

Comment: Finally, it's worth noting that N,S,E,W are simply conventions. The easiest answer to your question as-stated is "sure, redefine E/W as N/S and you're done." The axis of rotation can be shifted (theoretically) from perpendicular to the solar-polar plane (parallel with the sun's poles) to parallel with the solar-polar plane (the axis points toward the sun) and I'm wondering if it can be tangential to the orbit (the planet rolls "up" rather than "sideways"), but none of this might really matter since NSEW is just a convention. Want to see what it would look like? (\*continued\*)

Comment: Depending on your convention, either face the sun during sunrise or turn your left shoulder to it and look straight ahead. Out of curiosity, why are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

<sup>(Ignoring the part about the *"magnetic field"*. Magnets are not related to sunrise and sunset.)</sup>

*North* is the pole around which the planet rotates counterclockwise.

- That's the older definition, generalizable to any planet in any solar system.
- For reasons of its own, the International Astrononomical Union is peddling a newer, and not generalizable, definition, according to which north the pole which points to the same side of the ecliptic as Earth's north pole.

Taking the older (and truest) definition, we see that the Sun must needs to rise somewhere on the eastern half of the horizon, and set somewhere on the western side of the horizon. In the vast majority of imaginable situations, the Sun will set to a point almost symmetrical with the point from where it rose with respect to the meridian, that is, the north-south line.

(The newer definition allows the Sun to rise somewhere on the western half of the horizon and set somewhere on the estern half of the horizon, if the planet happens to be spinning in the opposite direction with respect to Earth's spin.)

Now coming to the question, *"is it possible for planet in any star system to have sunrise in the northern or southern pole"*: it is perfectly possible here on Earth for the Sun to rise (and of course set) *very close* to the north; it happens every year near the northern solstice in any place just south of the northern polar circle, for example, [Rørvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B8rvik) in Norway, at 64° 52′ N.

- The northern solstice is the solstice which happens in June; it's the point where the Sun reaches its northernmost position at noon. For people in the northern hemisphere, it is the summer solstice; for people in the southern hemisphere, it is the winter solstice.
- The northward equinox is the equinox which happens in March; it's the point when the apparent path of the Sun crosses the ecliptic from south to north. For people in the northern hemisphere, it is the spring equinox; for people in the southern hemisphere it is the autum equinox.

That's because Earth's axis of rotation is tilted with respect to its orbital plane; as a result, the Sun appears to be rising exactly east and setting exactly west only two times per year, at the equinoxes. For half a year, from the northward equinox to the southward equinox, the sun appears to be rising north of east and setting north of west; for the other half of the year, the sun rises south of east and sets south of west.

How much north (or south) can sunrise and sunset get?

All the way up to almost full north or full south.

Consider a place on the Equator. In such a place, at the northern solstice, the Sun will rise 23°30′ north of east, and set 23°30′ north of west. (That's exactly the angle Earth's axis of rotation is tilted with respect to its orbital plane.)

Now consider a point on the northen polar circle. In such a place, in the absence of atmospheric refraction, at the northern solstice the sun *would* appear to rise and set exactly north. (But it won't, because (1) the Sun is an extended object, not a point source of light, and because (2) atmospheric refraction tends to lift up the Sun's image when near the horizon. In reality, the Sun would appear to circle around the horizon without ever going fully below it.)

In our chosen place, Rørvik in Norway, at the northern solstice the sun rises only 19° east of north and then goes around the horizon to set 19° west of north. (Actually even closer to north, because of points (1) and (2) above.)

People at moderate latitudes also experience this effect, but in moderation. For example, at 45° latitude north, at the northern solstice the sun rises 34° north of east and sets 34° north of west; that's respectively northeast by east and northwest by west.

Comment: @JohnDvorak: I have incorporated your suggested edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue of language. Sunrise and sunset are caused by rotation of the planet (or similar body) around an axis. The axis defines the polar regions, north and south. The example of Uranus pointing one of its poles toward the sun would not result in a sunset or a sunrise, at least not in the short term.

An observer at one of the poles would experience a day that was equal to the length of the time it would take the planet to revolve around the central sun. Depending upon how far the planet was from that central star, there would be a sunset lasting for weeks, months, and in the case of Uranus, years, followed by a long period of darkness (months and years, again) followed by a subset of very long duration. Probably not what you had in mind, but who knows.

It is possible but not plausible that a binary or higher-order sun system might give you what you want. I suspect that these systems might provide the environment that you need for your story but it would not be a regular occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Happens to me every year. In the spring and late summer the sun rises and sets in the north. Pretty soon it's going to start rising and setting in the south.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where are you on the globe, roughly?

Comment: 69 degrees north (no, the number is not a joke, it's 69.1169 N).

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to achieve this is for the planet be on its side like Neptune, have a very long rotation period like Venus, but have a very small and fast orbit around the parent star (red dwarf?), so that the time it takes to revolve around the sun would be much shorter than the time it takes to turn around its axis.

Then from the perspective on the planet's surface, the sun will be rising at one pole and setting at the other, but I suspect it would be a wonky and irregular day cycle, certainly not similar to Earth's one.